# How can we get completion Time for individual transformation (like drop and rename) in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline, transformation

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
#Create spark session
data = [(“Banana”,1000,“USA”,“1”), (“Carrots”,1500,“USA”,“2"), (“Beans”,1600,“USA”,“3”),
      (“Orange”,2000,“USA”,“4"),(“Banana”,400,“China”,“5”),
      (“Carrots”,1200,“China”,“1"),(“Beans”,1500,“China”,“2”),(“Orange”,4000,“China”,“3"),
      (“Banana”,2000,“Canada”,“4”),(“Carrots”,2000,“Canada”,“5"),(“Beans”,2000,“Mexico”,“6”),(“Orange”,2000,“USA”,“7")]
columns= [“Product”,“Amount”,“Country”,“Id”]
spark = SparkSession.builder.master(“local[*]“).getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df=df.drop(“Id”)
df=df.withColumnRenamed(“Product”,“Veggies”)
df.write.csv(“Output.csv”)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Expecting Time interval for Individual  Transformation in Spark

Answer (score 0):

You can get Spark job execution details on Spark Master Web UI. Otherwise, need to implement your own approach, something simple would be as below **(Java code snippet, modify for Python as per your requirement)**,

```java
long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
.
.
.
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
.
.
.
long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
.
.
.
long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("1. Creating a session ........... " + (t1 - t0));
System.out.println("2. Loading initial dataset ...... " + (t2 - t1));
System.out.println("3. Transformations  ............. " + (t3 - t2));
System.out.println("4. Final action ................. " + (t4 - t3));
```